# I want to generate my matlab code from the .NET DLL file

Tags: .net, matlab

I have dll file generated from matlab code to .NET and I want to revert the process and get my matlab code back from dll file...can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The code is encrypted](http://de.mathworks.com/products/netbuilder/features.html#key-features) to protect it, the process can not be reversed.

Comment: so...no other ways :(